# ImageField uploads with Django Admin but not with template

Tags: python, django

I have the following form hooked to my Django Admin:

```py
# forms.py
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('name', 'profile_pic')

# admin.py
class ProfileAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = ProfileForm

admin.site.register(UserProfile, ProfileAdmin)

# models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Now if I upload the `profile_pic` with Django Admin, everything works fine. However, if I submit the image through my template, it doesn't work.

Here's my template:

```html
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form action="." enctype="multipart/form-data" id="userprofile_form" method="post">
  <h1> Update  your profile </h1>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div>
    {{ form }}
  <button class="border-2">Update Profile</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The corresponding view is this:

```py
@login_required
def get_profile(request):
    profile = request.user.userprofile
    form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'profile-edit.html', {'form':form})
```

In the view (inside `if form.is_valid()`), `form.cleaned_data` has value `None` for `profile_pic`. `request.FILES` is `<MultiValueDict: {'profile_pic': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: dave_pic.png (image/png)>]}>`

What's wrong with my upload logic. As I said, the same works just fine with Django Admin. `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` are all set.

Comment: OP here- I solved the issue, the line in the view should be: `form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)`. I am still not sure why and why such a point is not mentioned in any of the django documentation out there.

Answer (score 0):

I have been really struggling with the argument `instance` when calling a form. Sadly, even the Django official documentation that is supposedly "covers the gritty details of Django’s forms API" also fails to mention it even once (may be it's mentioned some where else, but I could not find it).

The updated view should be:

```py
@login_required
def get_profile(request):
    profile = request.user.userprofile
    form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile) # <---
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'profile-edit.html', {'form':form})
```

**Model Form initialization**
Model forms can use two initialization parameters: `initial` and `instance`. The `initial` argument works just like the standard initial form argument ... -- providing the initial values for an unbound form. The `instance` argument is used to initialize a model form with a model instance, which in turn is also used to initialize the values of an unbound form.
(source: [Beginning Django book](https://www.webforefront.com/django/modelformprocessing.html))

**Why Django Admin worked but not OP's approach?**
Actually, it always worked, except, when the `form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` was used, Django would create new `UserProfile` objects when the `form.save()` was encountered. This I confirmed by checking the `UserProfile` objects in the db. However, none of these were linked to the current user through `UserProfile.user` one-to-one field thus the changes would never affect the current user. When,`form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)` is used, the `user` field gets populated with the logged in user and things work as expected. When OP was updating the profile, no new `UserProfile` object was created and things would work fine.